# Is there any way to track file information (size,name,bucket location,create/update timestamp) in multiple google buckets

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm able to track the file ingress in a single bucket using below code. But I want to track all the files going into different buckets of my project on Google Cloud..is there any way?

```
def hello_gcs(event, context):
    """Triggered by a change to a Cloud Storage bucket.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    import os
    from google.cloud import bigquery

    BQ = bigquery.Client()
    table_id = 'xx.DW_STAGE.Bucket_Monitor'
    table = BQ.get_table(table_id)
  
    bucket=event['bucket']
    file_nm=event['name']
    create_ts=event['timeCreated']
    update_ts=event['updated']
    size=event['size']
    contentType=event['contentType']
    crc32c=event['crc32c']
    etag=event['etag']
    generation=event['generation']
    file_id=event['id']
    kind=event['kind']
    md5Hash=event['md5Hash']
    medialink=event['mediaLink']
    metageneration=event['metageneration']
    selfLink=event['selfLink']
    storageClass=event['storageClass']
    timeStorageClassUpdated=event['timeStorageClassUpdated']

    errors = BQ.insert_rows(table, [(bucket,file_nm,create_ts,update_ts,size,contentType,crc32c,etag,generation,file_id,kind,md5Hash,medialink,metageneration,selfLink,storageClass,timeStorageClassUpdated)])  # Make an API request.
    if errors == []:
        print("New rows have been added.")
    else:
        print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will be interested in [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub).  This mechanism is used underneath by Cloud Function Storage triggers (description is [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#event_delivery_mechanism)).

For every of your buckets you can create Pub/Sub [notification](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications) in the same topic (How to create notification you may find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes)). Every notification can has [attributes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#attributes) and [payload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications#payload) which contain information about the object which changed.

Such notification can be used as [trigger for Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions_calling_pubsub-python) similar to yours.

Comment: can we publish from multiple google buckets into single topic? or is there a one-to-one relationship between topic and bucket as far as pub/sub is concerned?

Comment: Yes, you can submit notification to the same topic, that a main point. I have updated the info in the answer

Comment: I got you now. Would you be able to guide me in finding out a way to identify which all sources are feeding into a topic?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Try to add pub/sub to your projects and notification for the buckets, then create a pub/sub triggered function. If you find any troubles that you cannot resolve you can try to post it here on Stack. But please specify exactly the problem you are dealing with at the moment